# Where should the top of stack be in linked list implementation of stack?

Tags: stack, linked-list

Here is what a linked list implementing a stack with 3 elements might look like:

```
list
 |
 v
--------   --------   ---------
| C | -+-->| B | -+-->| A | 0 |
--------   --------   ---------
```

Where should we consider the top of the stack to be, the beginning or end of the list, and why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest element to access in a linked list is usually the head (some implementations also keep a reference to the tail element though). Since the stack only ever needs to access the top element, that should be the head element of the linked list. This will avoid having to iterate over the entire list for every operation.

Comment: I am much confused where would the top of stack be here? As the top of stack points to the memory location where the next element will be stored, we don't a reserved memory location here.

Answer (score 0):

list.head will be top of the stack. Elements will be add in head like

**Insert(L,x)**

```
1. x.next = head.next
2. head = x
```

Similarly deletion will be performed in head.

**Delete(L)**

```
1. x=head
2. head = head.next 
3. Free x
```

In this way insertion and deletion will be in performed in LIFO order which is Stack.